# icon (.ico) is not showing in Python

Tags: python

Does anyone know why the icon (.ico) picture is not showing? When I right click it, it appears to be pointing to the right file though.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I remember problems with different color-depth when using this a few years ago. Did you try to edit / revise the icon-file & save it in different color-depth settings?

Comment: Perhaps it is because you are on a mac, and so it's not displaying correctly, but I'm not sure.

Comment: No I didn't save the icon in different color-depth settings. How do you do that? All I have done so far is trying out a bunch of pictures, including .ico I downloaded directly on the Internet, but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"Does anyone know why the icon (.ico) picture is not showing? "*

I can confirm to have routinely used the `.iconbitmap()`-method on cross-platform portable GUI-system for Linux / Win ecosystems years ago.

@DapperDuck hypothesis seems to be hard-coded right into the `__doc__`-string:

```
>>> print root.iconbitmap.__doc__
Set bitmap for the iconified widget to BITMAP. Return
        the bitmap if None is given.

        Under Windows, the DEFAULT parameter can be used to set the icon
        for the widget and any descendents that don't have an icon set
        explicitly.  DEFAULT can be the relative path to a .ico file
        (example: root.iconbitmap(default='myicon.ico') ).  See Tk
        documentation for more information.
```

So the Mac-specific documentation is to be consulted.